# Include file contents using m4 without processing them?

Tags: m4

I know that it is possible using GNU m4 `undivert`,
and in other implementations using `paste`.
But is there any way to do it without being implementation-specific?

Comment: `undivert` should work on every POSIX-compatible `m4`. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/m4.html

Comment: About `undivert` in the link: "The behavior is unspecified if an argument contains any non-numeric characters." So I think `undivert(filename)` is not portable at all.

Answer (score 1):

You may call an external command using the `syscmd` macro.

```
syscmd(`cat hello.c')dnl
```

**Note:** A text inserted literally in a diversion is scanned by M4 so you can't copy the contents of the file manually.

```
$ m4 foo
define(`foo', `FOO')dnl
divert(`1')dnl
foo
divert`'dnl
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
undivert(`1')dnl
=> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
=> FOO
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the other answer, also `undivert(path/to.txt)` works, but probably only with gnu m4. As @uzsolt's comment says, it [violates the posix standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/m4.html) (on which, the only acceptabler parameter is a number between 0 and 9, containing a temporary buffer).

Comment: After some experimenting, the decision was made to use cpp (c preprocessor) instead m4.